# View Vista Local Admins While Not Being Admin

Tags: windows-vista

In Vista (business edition), how can you view who the local admins are on the PC without the user being an admin?  Any command prompt method etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a command-prompt and execute:

```
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators
```

That will show you the membership of the local Administrators group on that machine. (Obviously, I'm assuming that the "Administrators" group hasn't been renamed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can always open a command-line prompt and type `net user` to list local users. Then type `net user <username>` for each of them to list the groups they belong to. You may infer something from the result; for example, a user belonging to a group named "Administrators" is *probably* a local admin.